# A list that holds the latest 10 values

Tags: java, android-studio

I am trying to create a list that holds up to the latest 10 values, however, these values need to be the latest. For example, I have a loop that outputs 100 numbers but only the lastest 10 numbers should be saved in this list.

Can anyone help me with this scenario as I am stuck and new to JAVA?

Comment: You're looking for something like that: [Ring Buffer in Java](//stackoverflow.com/q/7266042)

Comment: I looked at this and seems what I need, however when implementing the CircularFifoBuffer in the android studio it does not exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library it has `EvictingQueue`

```
    EvictingQueue<String> queue = EvictingQueue.create(10);
    //code test
     //add 100 strings to queue 
        for(int i =0;i<100;i++){
                    queue.add ("some text " + i);
                }
  //Iterate through array and print
  for(String x: queue){
            System.out.println (x);
        }

Output: 
Some Text90
Some Text91
Some Text92
Some Text93
Some Text94
Some Text95
Some Text96
Some Text97
Some Text98
Some Text99
```

It's Android compatible, but `'com.google.common.collect.EvictingQueue' is marked unstable with @Beta` :

```
implementation("com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-android")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply create a List with limitation, by extending an existing List-Implementation and overriding the `add`-method like this:

```java
class LimitedList<E> extends LinkedList<E> {
  private final int maxElements;

  public LimitedList(int maxElements) {
    this.maxElements = maxElements;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean add(E e) {
    if(this.size() > maxElements - 1) {
      this.remove(0);
    }
    return super.add(e);
  }
}
```

Note: in `ArrayList` there are also other methods to add elements, so maybe these also need to be overriden.

Comment: Testing this out seems interesting!

Comment: Elements are added to it, however more than the maxElements are still being inserted

Comment: I downvote this because it is a really bad implementation. Every time something is added, the whole array-1 has to be copied. You could even use a list and have and additional index for next insertion and replace that indicated element there. Best to go with @tom 's suggestion of using a proper RingBuffer.

Comment: @JayC667 You're right: Using LinkedList should solve this.